# How to get the same value from two arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get the same value from two arrays. Example:

```
a[] = array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);
b[] = array(c,d,o,l,p,i,u,y);
```

I want `c[]=c,d;`

Comment: By what criteria do you want to select c and d? Can you try describing in more detail?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr = array_intersect(array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
                       array('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'));

print_r(array_values($arr));
```

Answer (score 12):

see http://docs.php.net/array_intersect:

> array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1  that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

```
$a = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
$b = array('c','d','o','l','p','i','u','y');
$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
var_dump($c);
```

prints

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
}
```

Comment: to get rid of the keys, you can use `array_values(array_intersect($a, $b))`

Answer (score 5):

Try `$result = array_intersect($a, $b);`

Answer (score 3):

Use `array_intersect($a,$b)`
 -- Ohh many guys answered before i typed

Answer (score 0):

in_array() might be what you're looking for

Use in_array() to see if the value you're looking for is in both arrays a and b and then put it in array c (following your example)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function.

Comment: You could improve your post by adding an example how it could be used.