# How to merge two arrays in php

Tags: php, laravel

i am stuck at one point I have two arrays one contains read data and anther contains write as shown below

read array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => master/city
    [1] => master/national_holiday
    [2] => master/operator_comments
    [3] => master/sensors
)
```

write array

```
Array
(
    [0] => master/city
    [1] => master/national_holiday
)
```

I want to combine these two arrays. And i want as below

```
    Array
(
    ['master/city'] => 'read/write'
    ['master/national_holiday'] => 'read/write'
    ['master/operator_comments'] => 'read'
    ['master/sensors'] => 'read'
)
```

is it possible like this?

Comment: There is so many in this site ! You should find and try first ... :)

Comment: I have use array_flip() and try to append in value but it doesn't give expected result!
I am confuse what to use??

Comment: @David you have refrence site please provide me... :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272041/how-to-get-the-same-value-from-two-arrays-in-php ,that can get your same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   // we need somed 
   $read = array('master/city',
          'master/national_holiday',
          'master/operator_comments',
            'master/sensors');
  // Write variable 
 $write = array('master/city','master/national_holiday');

 $newarray = array();
 foreach($read as $key => $value)
 {
 // check value in another array 
 if(in_array($value,$write))
  {
    $access = 'read/write';
  }
 else
  {
    $access = 'read';
  }

 $newarray[$value] = $access;
 }

print_r($newarray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

Here is [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/dE44v)

```
$final = [];
array_walk($read,function($v,$k) use (&$final,&$write){
    if(array_search($v,$write) > -1){
        $final[$v] = 'read/write';
    }
    else{
        $final[$v] = 'read';
    }
});
print_r($final);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [master/city] => read/write
    [master/national_holiday] => read/write
    [master/operator_comments] => read
    [master/sensors] => read
)
```

**EDIT**
Please check this for better result in different array input as per the discussion with `Dhanashri`:

```
$read_flipped = array_flip($read);
$read_new = array_fill_keys(array_keys($read_flipped), 'read');               

$write_flipped = array_flip($write);
$write_new = array_fill_keys(array_keys($write_flipped), 'write');



$final = [];
$arr3 = array_merge_recursive($read_new,$write_new);

array_walk($arr3,function($v,$k) use (&$final) {
    if(is_array($v)){
        $final[$k] = 'read/write';
    }
    else{
        $final[$k] = $v;
    }
});
print_r($final);
```

Comment: can you chech this https://3v4l.org/tNY49

Comment: I'll check & update you

Comment: Check this: https://3v4l.org/hC3dI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112991/discussion-between-dhanashri-and-ali).

Answer (score 1):

```
 $read = array
(
    "master/city",
    "master/national_holiday",
    "master/operator_comments",
    "master/sensors",
);

$write = array(
    "master/city",
    "master/national_holiday",
 );


$new_array = array_merge($read,$write);
$your_array = array();
foreach($new_array as $key => $value ){ 
         $your_array[$value] =  (array_key_exists($value,$your_array)) ? "read/write" :  "read";
}
var_dump($your_array);
```

O/p

```
array (size=4)
  'master/city' => string 'read/write' (length=10)
  'master/national_holiday' => string 'read/write' (length=10)
  'master/operator_comments' => string 'read' (length=4)
  'master/sensors' => string 'read' (length=4)
```

You Can also Do same thing Using

```
$new_array = array_merge($read,$write);
$new_array2 = $new_array;
array_filter($new_array,function($value){
    global $new_array;
    $new_array[$value] = (array_key_exists($value,$new_array))? "read/write" : "read";
});
var_dump(array_diff($new_array, array_merge($new_array2)));
```

Comment: but @shivani if i am passing only write array then output show read basically output show write not read

Comment: You need to modify than.